# What is the meaning of the syntax appearing to destructure an array into an object?

Tags: javascript, syntax, destructuring

I'm reading this [Medium article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/higher-order-functions-composing-software-5365cf2cbe99) on functional programming and I am seeing a syntax I'm not familiar with. Wondering if anyone can shed some light? It looks almost as if the author is destructuring the entire array into an object, but I don't think that's possible for one, and for two, I'm not sure what purpose it'd serve in this function... Does anyone know what's happening here exactly?

```
const reduce = (reducer, initial, arr) => {
  // shared stuff
  let acc = initial;
  for (let i = 0, { length } = arr; i < length; i++) {//<-- {length} = arr ??
    // unique stuff in reducer() call
    acc = reducer(acc, arr[i]);
  // more shared stuff
  }
  return acc;
};
reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0, [1,2,3]); // 6
```

Comment: Every array is an object. And object destructuring means what it always means: `length = arr.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Array will have a length as property
   `const x = [1,2,3]; console.log(x.length); // logs 3`
2. And you can destructure the object like below

   const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
   const {a, b} = obj;
   console.log(a, b); // logs 1,2
3. You can declare new variables by commas initiating with as var, let, const.

> 'y' is also a let variable below

```
let x = 0, y = 1;
console.log(x, y) // logs 0, 1
```

4. `let i = 0, { length } = arr;` is explained as arr is array where it has length as property.

   let i = 0, {length} = arr; // written in shorthand for declaring the variable

Can be written like

```
let i = 0;
let {length} = arr;
```

5. If you want to destructure an array you won't use `{}` instead you'll be using `[]`

   const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
   const [a, b, ...c] = arr;
   console.log(a, b, c) // logs 1, 2, [3,4,5]

I hope it's clear now

Comment: oh man! yes i do get it. very clear, thank you for taking the time to #explainlikeimfive. I'm still getting acquainted with some of the novel features in es6 so i forget basic stuff, but yes. it's obvious now. d'oh! <--felt dumb. might delete later.

Comment: Happy learning. You'll get accustomed real soon. I wouldn't suggest you delete it because others could find it useful.